# Basis vectors for quantum electrodynamics

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, dirac-equation, spinors

The following unnormalized vectors are solutions to the Dirac equation.

\begin{align*}
u_1&=\begin{pmatrix}E+m\\0\\p_z\\p_x+ip_y\end{pmatrix}
\exp\left(\frac{i\phi}{\hbar}\right)
%
& v_1&=\begin{pmatrix}E-m\\0\\p_z\\p_x+ip_y\end{pmatrix}
\exp\left(-\frac{i\phi}{\hbar}\right)
\\[1ex]
u_2&=\begin{pmatrix}0\\E+m\\p_x-ip_y\\-p_z\end{pmatrix}
\exp\left(\frac{i\phi}{\hbar}\right)
%
& v_2&=\begin{pmatrix}0\\E-m\\p_x-ip_y\\-p_z\end{pmatrix}
\exp\left(-\frac{i\phi}{\hbar}\right)
\\[1ex]
u_3&=\begin{pmatrix}p_z\\p_x+ip_y\\E-m\\0\end{pmatrix}
\exp\left(\frac{i\phi}{\hbar}\right)
%
& v_3&=\begin{pmatrix}p_z\\p_x+ip_y\\E+m\\0\end{pmatrix}
\exp\left(-\frac{i\phi}{\hbar}\right)
\\[1ex]
u_4&=\begin{pmatrix}p_x-ip_y\\-p_z\\0\\E-m\end{pmatrix}
\exp\left(\frac{i\phi}{\hbar}\right)
%
& v_4&=\begin{pmatrix}p_x-ip_y\\-p_z\\0\\E+m\end{pmatrix}
\exp\left(-\frac{i\phi}{\hbar}\right)
\end{align*}

where

\begin{equation*}
E=\sqrt{p_x^2+p_y^2+p_z^2+m^2}
\end{equation*}

and

\begin{equation*}
\phi=p_xx+p_yy+p_zz-Et
\end{equation*}

Of course, quantum electrodynamics uses the following solutions
(in their normalized form) because the mass term $m$ is positive.

\begin{align*}
u_1 &\quad \text{fermion, spin up}
\\
u_2 &\quad \text{fermion, spin down}
\\
v_3 &\quad \text{anti-fermion, spin up}
\\
v_4 &\quad \text{anti-fermion, spin down}
\end{align*}

What other combinations of $u$ and $v$ could be used as a basis
for quantum electrodynamics?
Are there any theories that use a different basis?

There are ${8\choose4}=70$ ways to choose four vectors,
but not all of them are linearly independent.

Comment: I don't think it's right to make the general statement that QED uses a specific choice of basis. It may be the case that one choice is conventional or particularly convenient for a particular application, of course. And since a choice of basis is ultimately unphysical (in the sense that it has no physical ramifications), picking a different one doesn't give you a new theory in any meaningful sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By brute force checking of all 70 determinants,
there are 16 choices of basis vectors.

\begin{equation*}
\begin{matrix}
u_1 u_2 v_1 v_2 & u_1 u_4 v_1 v_2 & u_2 u_3 v_1 v_2 & u_3 u_4 v_1 v_2
\\
u_1 u_2 v_1 v_4 & u_1 u_4 v_1 v_4 & u_2 u_3 v_1 v_4 & u_3 u_4 v_1 v_4
\\
u_1 u_2 v_2 v_3 & u_1 u_4 v_2 v_3 & u_2 u_3 v_2 v_3 & u_3 u_4 v_2 v_3
\\
u_1 u_2 v_3 v_4 & u_1 u_4 v_3 v_4 & u_2 u_3 v_3 v_4 & u_3 u_4 v_3 v_4
\end{matrix}
\end{equation*}